# Mongoid has_many & embeds_one to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have three models

```
Company
Shipping_method
Order
```

A Company can have many shipping_methods & when a user puts an order, he can choose a shipping_method for the Order.

Once a user select a shipping_method & put the order, even the shipping_method changes from the company level, it should not be changed in the order.

This is my implementation so far,

```
class ShippingMethod
include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :is_default, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :remove_image, type: Boolean, default: false

  belongs_to :ownable,          polymorphic: true
end
```

Order Class

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one  :shipping_method
end
```

Company Class

```
class OfficeGroup
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :shipping_methods,         as: :ownable,           autosave: true
end
```

All the things between Company & shipping method are working fine. But once I try to assign a shipping_method to an Order. I cannot update that shipping_method inside the order. This is how I try to update the shipping_method inside the order.

```
shipping_method = ShippingMethod.find("id here")
order.shipping_method = shipping_method
order.save
```

What's wrong with my relationship? Can someone please explain

Comment: `I cannot update that shipping_method inside the order.` means? how you are trying to udate? what error you are getting?

Comment: updated the question